# Display white spaces that precede the content of the line of the file - PHP

Tags: php, html, whitespace

I'm currently using foreach loop to display the contents of a text file. However, I want to also display the whitespaces that precede the actual content of the line. How to do so?

```
$loop_var = 0;
    foreach($lines as $line) {  
        $loop_var++;
        if ($loop_var == 1) {
            echo'<div id="h1">' . $line . '</div>';
        }
        if ($loop_var == 2) {
            echo '<div id="h2">' . $line . '</div><br />';
        }
        if ($loop_var > 2) {
            if ($loop_var == 3) { echo '<pre><div id="code">'; }
            echo ($line) . "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo '</pre></div>';
```

Now, if the textfile contains the following:

```
blah
blah
    blah
  blah
```

It is getting displayed as:

```
blah

blah

    blah

  blah
```

Comment: I've re-tagged your question as HTML, assuming that's what you're talking about. Try to use tags that describe the language and/or technology your question is about; Stack Overflow is a forum that covers all programming languages.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I thought it was more of a PHP problem than an HTML problem.

Comment: Why should PHP remove white space and not, e.g., letter `c`? ;-)

Comment: And one more thing: in the end you switched the closed tags : `echo '</pre></div>'`

And if you want less tags to use, you does not need to use `<div>` inside the `pre` tag, just add the `id="code"` to `pre`

Comment: How did I not think of that.. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<pre>` tag, and print the content of textfile into this.
example:

```
print '<pre>'.file_get_contents('filename.txt').'</pre>';
```

Line By line (With conditions)

```
$file = fopen('filename','r');

print '<pre>';
$counter = 0;
while( $line = fgets($file) ){
   if(  /*the condition comes here whitch line you want to print. example: */ $counter >= 2  ){
        print $line;
   }
   if(  /*the condition comes here where wants you end the printing. example: */ $counter >= 10 )
   $counter++;
}
print '</pre>';

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Actually that doesn't help my case since I don't want to display the entire file in one go since the first two lines contain some different information.

Comment: This is only an example. I tought you have the other parts of the code.
I edit the answer with a line by line solution

Comment: Okay nevermind, I got the gist. But instead of display the preceding characters it adds a newline before the line.

Comment: Well, it works. I forgot to remove a piece of code I had added to handle this. However, the newline problem still persists.

Comment: `<br/>` is not needed if you use `<pre>` or you can use `nl2br($line)`
and this converts line endings to `<br/>` tag, if you want to use `<br/>`. but the extra <br/> in your code causes the extra line break. in `<pre>` tag the line breaks shows as real line break in html too.

Answer (score 1):

When you read text from a file and output that text again, the whitespace is still there.

But:  if you are outputting HTML, and viewing the output in a browser, the whitespace is ignored. That's just the normal way html is displayed by a browser.

Use your browser to view the HTML source code  (e.g. CTRL-U in firefox) to check if this is the case.

If you want the whitespace to be displayed in your webpage you can use the pre-Tag, or use the CSS property "whitespace" http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp.

```
  <pre><?php echo $file_content ?></pre>
```

or

```
  <p style="whitespace:pre;"><?php echo $file_content ?></p>
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/CjXMe/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can brute-force it if you wish ... only in case you're really stuck!

1)  Get the length of the string with **strlen()**

2)  Run a loop on the characters in the string and check for a space with **strpos**

3)  Concatenate an html space to an empty string and print before-hand

```
$str = " whatever is in here ... ";
$spaces = "";
for( $i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++ ){
    if( strpos( $str, ' ', $i ) ){
        $spaces .= "&nbsp;";
    }
}
```